# Map union to interface properties

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to map a union type to interface in Typescript?

What I'd Like to be able to do

Given a union type A:

```
type A = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
```

I'd like to be able to map it to interface B:

```
interface B {
    one:   boolean;
    two:   boolean;
    three: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) make this surprisingly easy:

```typescript
type A = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';

type B = {
    [property in A]: boolean;
};
```

`B` ends up being:

```typescript
{
    one:   boolean;
    two:   boolean;
    three: boolean;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkB7AdhJUA+zgHcUtclgALAJwkwG4BYAKEdEigCEEoBvRqPqANpgKKSBVBQAlmlgBdAFxQARihQAbCAEM09BgF9djAMboAzsGWKOiHg35R0ERcAoBXCABpe-AikUAzTTVTT28+cionKBd3L30aIA)

But as [Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l) points out, there's a utility type for that: [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```typescript
type B = Record<A, boolean>;
```

With mapped types, you can even make the types of the properties different by throwing [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) into the mix:

```typescript
type A = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';

type B = {
    [property in A]: property extends 'one' ? number : boolean;
};
```

`B` ends up being:

```typescript
{
    one:   number;
    two:   boolean;
    three: boolean;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkB7AdhJUA+zgHcUtclgALAJwkwG4BYAKEdEigCEEoBvRqPqANpgKKSBVBQAlmlgBdAFxRhoiOJBQIAD2AQ0AEwDOydJigB+KGgCuAWwBGqqIrsoUAGwgBDNPQYBfX0YAY3QDYCg7RQ5EHgZ+KBNFABYAJgAaXn4CFEUAM083AwgMuKzKakVgCisIRgCgA)

Comment: Also there's a handy shortcut `Record<A, boolean>` (when all properties have the same type) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype

Comment: @AlekseyL. - Doh! I knew about `Record` but shockingly didn't think of it for this...